# How to set path for JDK?

Tags: java, javac

I am using windows 8. I have set environment as path having value C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\bin. But still i am getting error while compiling java file as

```
javac: file Not found: fileName.java
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
```

Comment: What does the command line you execute look like exactly?

Comment: So, the compiler can be found and works fine. But you ask it to compile a .java file that doesn't exist.

Comment: Are you executing the `javac fileName.java` command in the directory where the `fileName.java` file is located? The error message would suggest you're not.

Comment: @mcandre I didn't know it did that. Same as in most *NIX shells then (and maybe not so silly).

Comment: @mcandre that's completely useless. javac doesn't care about the PATH variable. It compiles the files you tell it to compile, and resolves the relative paths from the current directory.

Comment: Where is fileName.java in your directories, and what's your current directory? `javac` will not search paths for source files; you need to tell it specifically which file you want to compile. (As opposed to `java`, which searches the `CLASSPATH`.) Sun recommends: [Arrange source files in a directory tree that reflects their package tree. For example, if all of your source files are in \workspace, then put the source code for com.mysoft.mypack.MyClass in /workspace in \workspace\com\mysoft\mypack\MyClass.java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html)

Comment: My file name is demo.txt which i want to compile. I have placed that file at D:\Rohit. Before compilation, I set the directory D:\Rohit, then i set the path as set path =C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\bin. after that i am executing Javac demo.java command. But, i am getting error like  "javac: file Not found: fileName.java
Usage: javac <options> <source files>"

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify files to compile (space delimited if multiple). If just by name, they must be in the current folder. The path concept will not work here, all files that must be compiled should be directly specified in the input. Normally `javac` compiler alone is only used if you only need to compile one or two files as proof of concept.

Use more advanced command line tool like [ant](http://ant.apache.org/) (works under Windows) for the real world size projects.

Comment: My file name is demo.txt which i want to compile. I have placed that file at D:\Rohit. Before compilation, I set the directory D:\Rohit, then i set the path as set path =C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\bin. after that i am executing Javac demo.java command. But, i am getting error like "javac: file Not found: fileName.java Usage: javac <options> <source files>"

Answer (score 0):

MyComputer >> System Properties >>Advanced System Settings >>  Environment Variables under that add

PATH - c:/blah/java/jdk1.6/bin;    //add your bin you have shown above and 
CLASSPATH - .;  // dont miss tht semicolons at the end .

thats all i did . in Win 8

Comment: My file name is demo.txt which i want to compile. I have placed that file at D:\Rohit. Before compilation, I set the directory D:\Rohit, then i set the path as set path =C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\bin. after that i am executing Javac demo.java command. But, i am getting error like "javac: file Not found: fileName.java Usage: javac <options> <source files>"